# Selenium Proxy Error when intializing webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

When using selenium for work behind enterprise firewall, it's necessary to connect to proxy to access internet. However, selenium is returning proxy error even when initializing the webdriver.

```
from selenium import webdriver

proxy='x.x.x.x:xxx'
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={proxy}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Getting `401` unauthorized error even before visiting any webpage.

Answer (score 0):

After exhaustive search to no avail. Because the webdriver initialization only connects to localhost, it shouldn't need proxy. Adding the '--no-proxy-server' option resolved this issue. This was suggested by chatgpt but not for the right reason.

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument(f'--no-proxy-server')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```